# Календарь - онлайн запись на сайте

Tags: wordpress

Для сайта компании информационных услуг нужно реализовать **календарь - онлайн запись,** где есть возможность видеть свободное время и отправка записи на желаемое время и услугу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если сайт интегрирован с WordPress, то как будет проще и лучше такое реализовать?

С помощью **Google Calendar API** такое можно сделать? Или для этого нужно использовать другие сервисы, плагины WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> С помощью Google Calendar API такое можно сделать? Или для этого нужно
>   использовать другие сервисы, плагины WordPress?

Использовать плагины и сделать как угодно. Хоть с  помощью Google Calendar API хоть без оного.